# Selecting entities if their (datetime2(7))date field + (bigint)timespan field is > DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Let's say user have subscription for notifications that starts at certain point in time and lasts for a time span. So in our model we will have two relevant fields `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`. Now our `DateTime` field will map to `datetime(7)`, but since there is no direct mapping between `CLR` `TimeSpan` to some `SQL type`, we have to store our `TimeSpan` as `Int64` in our model, add accessor and mutator that will allow us to use a `TimeSpan` in our code, and to store as `bigint` in the database.

```
public class CustomerMemebership
{
    public Int      CustomerId    { get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public Int64    timeSpan      { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeSpan
    {
        get { return TimeSpan.FromTicks(timeSpan); }
        set { timeSpan = value.Ticks; }
    }
}

db.CustomerMemberships.Where(cm => DateTime.UtcNow < DbFunctions.AddNanoseconds(cm.EffectiveDate, cm.timeSpan * 100))
```

Mapping to `SQL Time` is no go, since `Time` is 5 bytes and `TimeSpan` is 8 bytes. How would I get the entities that have active subscription? `DbFunctions.AddNanoseconds` only accepts `int32`, since it maps to `SQL DATEADD` which also work only with 32-bit integers. Or may be I'm doing it all wrong?

Comment: Having two public properties, of different type, that are named the same and differ only by the case of the first letter will very likely confuse the consumers of your type.  Consider renaming "timeSpan" to "timeSpanInTicks" or something like that.  Just a helpful suggestion from someone who spends too much time reading other people's code

Comment: @JayV I'm afraid you did, since I'm asking about `EF` `LINQ to Entities` which cannot translate `DateTime.Add(TimeSpan)` into SQL...

Comment: @Flydog57, firstly it's well documented, secondly one of them is property the other one is a field, besides it's not being exposed to unaware programmers so not one is going to be confused, but thank you for you insight.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a suggestion, you can change your model. You have the `EffectiveDate` and the `TimeSpan`. You will need the end time of subscription, so instead of `TimeSpan` (in any format) you can calculate the end time and save it. then you can easily extract it.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, thought this cannot be accomplished in my specific situation, since the actual model is much more complicated than in the example I provided... Since it might be useful for googlers, I've marked it as useful answer.